# flutter : How to Update OverlayEntry value instead of create new one

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to use `OverlayEntry` on `onChanged` callback from TextField.

```
  body: Center(
    child: Container(
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        key: _textFieldKey,
        style: _textFieldStyle,
        onChanged: (String nextText) {
          showOverlaidTag(context, nextText);
        },
      ),
      width: 400.0,
    ),
  )
```

The problem is when everytime onChanged is triggered, new Overlay is created and lay on each other? I want to just new text replaced with new text and the old overlay remains?

```
  showOverlaidTag(BuildContext context, String newText) async {

      OverlayEntry suggestionTagoverlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => DropDownBody(
          focusNode: _focusNode,
          newText : newText
        ),
      );
      overlayState.insert(suggestionTagoverlayEntry);

      //await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10000));
      suggestionTagoverlayEntry.remove();
    
  }
```

This is `DropDownBody`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropDownBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDownBody({Key? key, required this.focusNode, required this.newText})
      : super(key: key);

  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final String newText;

  @override
  _DropDownBodyState createState() => _DropDownBodyState();
}

class _DropDownBodyState extends State<DropDownBody> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("=====> build");
    return Positioned(
      top: widget.focusNode.offset.dy + 50,
      left: 0,
      child: Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Show tag here',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I commented this `await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10000));` I want just one instance be created and just new text be change. but in my code every time I added new text one overlay instance created and laid on each other  @GoldenLion

Comment: look , https://pasteboard.co/iNrWn17fZBpN.png . a few instance is created  @GoldenLion

Comment: I added `dropdownbody` @GoldenLion

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix a few syntax errors in your code.  I implemented the dropdownbody code in part.  works great.

```
    class HomePageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePageWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final formKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController text_controller= TextEditingController();

  @override
  _HomePageWidgetState createState() => _HomePageWidgetState();
}
class _HomePageWidgetState extends State<HomePageWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text("test changenotify"),
      ),
      body: Form( key:widget.formKey, child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(icon:  const Icon(Icons.person),
            hintText: "Input some text",
            labelText:  "Input",
            ),
            onChanged: (String nextText){
              //debugPrint(nextText);
              showOverlaidTag(context,nextText);
              //Future<bool> val=showOverlaidTag(context,nextText);
              //val.then((result)=>result);
            },
            controller: widget.text_controller),
          ],
    )));
  }

  showOverlaidTag(BuildContext context, String newText) async {
      OverlayEntry suggestionTagoverlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => 
        Positioned(
          top:100,
          child: 
          Material(elevation:4.0,
          color:Colors.transparent,
        child:Container(
          width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
          color:Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          child:
          Row(children: [Expanded(child:        Text(
          //focusNode: _focusNode,
          newText
        ))],)
        ),
      )));
      //overlayState.insert(suggestionTagoverlayEntry);

      Overlay.of(context)?.insert(suggestionTagoverlayEntry);
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000));
      suggestionTagoverlayEntry.remove();
      return suggestionTagoverlayEntry;
    
  }

}
```

Comment: I test your code but still depend on how many words you added into text filed, OverlayEntry is instantiate many times . I want to just one time be OverlayEntry shown and just text value be changed @GoldenLion

Comment: I think loading is not the proper solution  for this issue, It blocks UI @GoldenLion

Comment: not possible using overlay. overlay must be call for each text update

Answer (score 0):

use boolean and try to call the insert only the first time

```
 if(isOverlayAlreadyRunning == false){ 
    entry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          
        );
      });
      overlay?.insert(entry!);
   isOverlayAlreadyRunning = true;
 }
```

and use setState((){}) to update the variable

Answer (score 0):

try this, did a little refactoring for the text, it doesn't change much. Call hideOverlay() when you want to remove it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class DropDownBody extends StatefulWidget {
      const DropDownBody({Key? key, required this.focusNode, required this.newText})
          : super(key: key);
    
      final FocusNode focusNode;
      final String newText;
    
      @override
      _DropDownBodyState createState() => _DropDownBodyState();
    }
    
    class _DropDownBodyState extends State<DropDownBody> {
      OverlayEntry? overlayEntry;
      String? text;
    
      void insertOverlay(BuildContext context) {
        if (overlayEntry == null || !overlayEntry!.mounted) {
          overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
            builder: (context) => DropDownBody(focusNode: _focusNode, newText: text??'sus')
          );
    
          final overlay = Overlay.of(context)!;
          overlay.insert(overlayEntry!);
        }
      }
    
      void hideOverlay() {
        overlayEntry!.remove();
        overlayEntry == null;
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print("=====> build");
        return Positioned(
          top: widget.focusNode.offset.dy + 50,
          left: 0,
          child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        'Show tag here',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        );
      }
    }
```